Serverless WebSocket Service for Real-Time Stock Data Processing
I'm looking for a serverless service that can be utilized as a socket API backend client. For example, if I have a stock-based socket API that provides real-time data on stock LTP (Last Traded Price), I have two scenarios:
Scenario 1: To consume data from the socket API, I have one option: write a script to consume the data, add my custom logic, and then host it on a VPC or AWS EC2 instance.
Scenario 2: If there's a serverless service that takes a WebSocket API and custom condition code, it could trigger events to AWS Lambda or other functions when conditions are met.
In Scenario 1, I have to do everything on my own and may face scalability or server issues. In Scenario 2, real-time API consumption and data analysis are done within the service, reducing infrastructure issues and making it easier to scale.
My main concern is finding a service that works as described in Scenario 2.
Is there any serverless service available that can handle WebSocket connections, process real-time data, and trigger events based on custom conditions without requiring me to manage the infrastructure?
I tried to find such a service online but didn't find any.

There are at least four ways you can implement WebSockets using Serverless:

API Gateway
AppSync
IoT Core
Momento Topics

There are various trade-offs based on development effort, cost, security etc.  For more info see https://theburningmonk.com/2024/04/here-are-four-ways-you-can-implement-websockets-using-serverless/
